# Is there a performance benefit of using CompletableFuture callbacks?

Tags: java, completable-future

CompletableFuture allows to provide callbacks for async calls. You can create a long chain of callbacks where each async call will trigger the next one on completion. This is deemed a better way to write async code instead of using Future where you've to block the thread to get the result of first computation before triggering the next one.

I can understand the argument that callback chains in Completable Futures can provide a more readable code but I'm wondering if there's a performance benefit as well to this approach or is it just a syntactic sugar?

For example, consider the following code:

```java
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(this::findAccountNumber, exec)
                     .thenApply(this::calculateBalance)
                     .thenApply(this::notifyBalance)
                     .thenAccept((i)->notifyByEmail())
                     .join();
```

In this code, `calculateBalance()` can't start until `findAccountNumber()` finishes so essentially `calculateBalance()` is blocked on `findAccountNumber()` and so on for the next methods in the callback chain. How is it better than the following (performance-wise):

```
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Future<Integer> accountNumberFuture = exec.submit(findAccountNumberCallable);
    Integer accountNumber = accountNumberFuture.get();
    Future<String> calculateBalanceFuture = exec.submit(calculateBalanceCallable(accountNumber);
    ....
    ....
```

Comment: In this example there is no reason to use CompletableFuture at all since you block everything anyway. The added executor is pointless overhead.

Answer (score 4):

In most cases, you won't notice a difference, but if you want to be able to have a lot of concurrent asynchronous calls waiting something, you'll want to use `CompletableFuture`.

The reason is that if you simply call `get()` on a regular `Future` the `Thread` and all resources associated with it become blocked until the call returns. If you have many calls your thread pool might get exhausted, or if you use a `CachedThreadPool` you might cause lots of threads to be created.

With `CompletableFuture`, an object is stored on the heap which represents where the application should pick up next, as opposed to using the call stack. The guy who built the API has a talk about it over [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lyJBtg6Dgwc).

Comment: Every object is on the heap, not sure what this has to do with futures. And calling `get()` on any future will have the same negative impact.

Comment: By surrendering the control of the current thread, you only take up space on the heap and not in a call stack, was my point above. Agreed that using `CompletableFuture` is moot if you end up calling `get()` at the end of your chain, but that's one general challenge of writing async code; it's very easy to turn it synchronous.